# How to count first occurence of a value in a dataframe of lists in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe which has one column of lists and one column with the number of objects in that list and is sorted by its descending order.
For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[['AB','BC','CD','DE','EF','FG','GH','HI'],
                          ['BC','CD','DE','IJ','JK','KL','LM'],
                          ['AB','CD','DE','MN'],
                          ['C', 'D', 'M'],
                          ['MN','NO'],
                          ['APQ']],
                 'no_of_values': [8,7,4,3,2,1]})
```

I would like to have a 3rd column with number of values that occur for the first time (from top to bottom). For example:

```
df_goal=pd.DataFrame({'value':[['AB','BC','CD','DE','EF','FG','GH','HI'],
                               ['BC','CD','DE','IJ','JK','KL','LM'],
                               ['AB','CD','DE','MN'],
                               ['C', 'D', 'M'],
                               ['MN','NO'],
                               ['APQ']],
                      'no_of_values': [8,7,4,3,2,1],
                      'no_of_1st_occurence': [8,4,1,3,1,1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a much more efficient way using `explode`:

```
df['no_of_1st_occurence'] = (~df['value'].explode().duplicated()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                              value  no_of_values  no_of_1st_occurence
0  [AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FG, GH, HI]             8                    8
1      [BC, CD, DE, IJ, JK, KL, LM]             7                    4
2                  [AB, CD, DE, MN]             4                    1
3                         [C, D, M]             3                    3
4                          [MN, NO]             2                    1
5                             [APQ]             1                    1
```